# Keep &nbsp; and other special characters in XSLT output with apply-templates

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, special-characters

I'm using XSLT to extract some HTML content with special characters (like `&nbsp;`) from an XML file. The content is stored in `<content>` nodes. I have defined most special characters like this: `<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">`, so this expression works perfectly fine:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Now, I want to add `target="_blank"` *to every link found within that content.* This is the solution I came up with:

```
<xsl:template match="a" mode="html">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|* "/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

And instead of the "copy-of" element I use this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="content" mode="html"/>
```

Now all those special characters (and nbsp too) disappeared from the output. How do I keep them? Seems like `disable-output-escaping="yes"` doesn't help here.

Ok, I'm using the XSLTProcessor class in PHP. The `disable-output-escaping` attribute didn't give an error actually, but when I removed it, the output was the same, with all the nbsp's, so it didn't matter.

---

UPD. With the XSL template I have shown before, my input sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE page SYSTEM "html-entities.xsl">
<content>There is a&nbsp;non-breaking <a href="http://localhost">space</a> inside.</content>
```

html-entities.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
```

PHP code:

```
$xp = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load($xsl_filename);
$xp->importStylesheet($xsl);
$xml_doc = new DOMDocument();
$xml_doc->resolveExternals = true;
$xml_doc->load($xml_filename);
$html = $xp->transformToXML($xml_doc);
```

My current output:

`There is anon-breaking <a href="http://localhost" target="_blank">space</a> inside.`

My desired output:

`There is a&nbsp;non-breaking <a href="http://localhost" target="_blank">space</a> inside.`

Comment: Would it be possible to show a sample of your 'content' XML? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any `disable-output-escaping` attribute on the `copy-of` element in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of so I would expect that your code sample `<xsl:copy-of select="content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` simply gives an error by the XSLT processor. Consider to show us more details on the input sample, the wanted output, the current output and the XSLT processor you use.

Comment: Ok, I'm using the XSLTProcessor class in PHP. The `disable-output-escaping` attribute didn't give an error actually, but when I removed it, the output was the same.

Comment: Updated my question, your thoughts please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically whether the source code of the input XML document has a character reference like `&#160;` or an entity reference like `&nbsp;` or such a character literally does not matter to XSLT and does not make a difference how the input is processed and how the output looks; basically XSLT operates on a tree with Unicode characters stored in text nodes. At least that is the theory, your PHP code seems to work with a DOM tree model which might store entity reference nodes but even then for XSLT that shouldn't matter. In the input tree there should be text nodes containing Unicode characters (one if which could be the non-breaking space character with Unicode 160) and if you copy such a text to the output the result tree has a text node with the same Unicode characters.

For the output method `html` some XSLT processors (Saxon 6.5.5 for instance) might do you the favour to ensure characters defined as entities in HTML are serialized with the corresponding entity reference but even if they don't do that the serialization of the result tree should be a file with the proper Unicode characters, encoded as directed by the `encoding` attribute of the `xsl:output` element.

Your current result which completely drops the character (e.g. `There is anon-breaking`) does not make sense to me.

Comment: Do you think my template which adds the `target="_blank"` attribute to links is written in a correct way?

Comment: I don't think that template matters, as the non-breaking space is not even inside of the `a` element, instead it is inside a sibling text node. If I were to write such a template, I would use `<xsl:template match="a[@href]"><a target="_blank"><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/></a></xsl:template>`. In your attempt the `<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></xsl:attribute>` looks odd as it populates the `href` with `@*` and not with `@href` (and `@*` will take the value of whichever attribute the current implementation considers the first on that run of the code).